# using std::move for return result of function

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

which is right?

```
std::string get_string()
{
    std::string result;
    // ... more operations.
    return std::move(result);
}
```

Or

```
   std::string&&  get_string()
   {

      std::string result;
      // ... more operations
      return std::move(result);
   }
```

?

If I use  std::move,  what should be type of function?

Comment: They're both wrong, the second more-so than the first. Return by value, and don't call `move` on the return expression.

Comment: Ok. Second version is wrong. but in the first version:
here is RVO always worked, because in my case  between result and return more 100 lines.
?